# Linux pipes in C

Tags: c, linux, file, pipe

I have the following code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

FILE *f,*stream1,*stream2,*stream3,*stream4;

int main()
{
    int pfd[2];
    int pfd1[2];
    int pfd2[2];
    int pid1;
    int pid2;

    pipe(pfd);
    pipe(pfd1);
    pipe(pfd2);

    f=fopen("date","r");
    pid1=fork();


    if(pid1==0){

        close(pfd[1]);

        stream2=fdopen(pfd[0],"r");

        char c;
        int rd=fread(&c,sizeof(char),1,stream2);
        while(rd!=0){
            printf("%c",c);
            rd=fread(&c,sizeof(char),1,stream2);
        }
        close(pfd[0]);
        exit(0);

    }

    pid2=fork();

    if(pid2==0){

        printf("second process\n");
        exit(0);

    }
    if(pid1>0&&pid2>0){
        close(pfd[0]);
        stream1=fdopen(pfd[1],"w");
        while(!feof(f)){
            char c;
            fscanf(f,"%c",&c);
            if(feof(f)) break;
            fwrite(&c,sizeof(char),1,stream1);
        }
        close(pfd[1]);
        exit(0);
    }
}
```

This code takes some input from a file and displays it in child1.
The problem is that whenever I want to close `pfd[1]` in the parent process, the output in child1 (`pid1`) doesn't show up. Why is this happening? If I don't close `pfd[1]` it goes normally.

Edit: I solve it .The problem was that i used fread,fwrite instead of read and write. With this in place everything runs as i wanted.

Comment: You should not call `exit` in both the parent and the child. This is a serious bug that has had severe security consequences in the past. Typically, the correct solution is for the child to call `_exit`. (Imagine, for example, if you call `fork` when the process' exit handlers are going to do something that must not happen more than once. Are you 100% sure all the `atfork` handlers will fix this? If not, don't `exit` twice.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems:

1) You are using `fdopen` and `fwrite` instead of writing to the pipe using `write`.

This is possible however `fwrite` will buffer the data before calling `write` internally.

When you call `fclose(stream1)` the `fclose` function will first write all buffered data using `write()` and then call `close(pfd[1])`.

However if you call `close(pfd[1])` directly the buffered data is not written to the pipe.

2) When a program finishes child processes are typically also killed.

Don't leave the `main` function until all child processes created using `fork` also have finished. (It does not matter if you use `return` or `exit()`).

Use the `waitpid` or the `wait4` function to wait for a child process to finish.

I compiled the program on my computer: Only when fixing *both* problems I get the desired result.